# How can I resolve my CSS flexbox problem?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I am working on a HTML / CSS / JS project and I'm currently editing a website to add a panel for notifications. Here is how it's supposed [to look like](https://i.postimg.cc/DzL7zWhL/image-2022-02-22-125900.png).

This is what [mine looks like](https://i.postimg.cc/0NsyDGcc/image-2022-02-22-130404.png).

How can I align my three items?

Here is my JavaScript code to write the HTML :

```js
function notifElement() {
  const notifUrl = 'https://smart4.io/centralizer';
  const container = document.createElement("div");
  //const aeL = document.createElement("a");

  container.id = "notif";
  const form = document.createElement("form");
  const leftArrow = document.createElement("button");
  leftArrow.name = 'leftButton'
  leftArrow.innerHTML = '&lt'

  const rightArrow = document.createElement("button");
  rightArrow.name = 'rightButton'
  rightArrow.innerHTML = '&gt'
 
  const middleContainer = document.createElement("div");
  middleContainer.id = "middle";
  const middlebutton = document.createElement("button");
  middlebutton.name = 'middleButton'

 
  const text = document.createElement('p')
  t.textContent = 'Lorem Ipsum';
  
  middleContainer.appendChild(t);
 
  form.appendChild(leftArrow);
  form.appendChild(middleContainer);
  form.appendChild(rightArrow);

  container.appendChild(form);
  return container;
 }
```

And here is my CSS code :

```css
#notif {
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 12em;
  z-index: 1;
  justify-content: center;
}

#notif > form {
  padding-right: 3em;
}

#notif > form > button {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS  add display flex to `#notif > form`.

```
#notif > form {
  padding-right: 3em;
  display:flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `justify-content: center;` with `justify-content: space-around;`. Also this property (justify-content) works with `display: flex;`.

```
#notify > form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```